# unable to access /mnt directory from third party application

Tags: 22.04

I am using ubuntu 22.04. And, I can't access files directly from these directory while using third party applications. Let's say I am using MySQL workbench, and when I try to export to or import from these directories, but it does not show directories. Same case for many more applications.

If I check `/mnt` directory it also shows empty.I am pretty new to ubuntu, so don't know how to fix.

Comment: Probably your third party applications are installed using Snap? These applications run in a security sandbox. Depending on the permissions, you can access files in your home directory and on automatically mounted drives (/media/user/...) only. So first see whether you cannot change your workflow.

Comment: do you as normal user who opens the third party applicatoins have acces to the /mnt folder in general? Can you browse in that folder as normal user or do you need sudo / root privileges? As last resort, you could try run the Appliaction as root and check if you can access that folder than. If not, perhaps as vanadium said you are in a sandbox environment like snap. If you are running that appliaction as root and you can access that folder, than it is a permissions problem. Some APPs use their own user/group to restrict permissions.

Comment: I am not familiar with mysql but is can be that it has created its own user/group which you need to give permissions to access the folder inside /mnt

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I don't need sudo privileges to open files in normal, previously, when I go to /mnt folder I used to see `D`, `E`, `F` drive but not on this ubuntu 22. And, its not on the applications limited to snap, applications like `Filezilla` are also unable to find other directory.

Comment: what do you mean by D,E,F drive? To me is sounds like Windows language where you have partitions or drives named C,D,E,F while in linux everything is a file or link. I am also confused when you say *previously, ... but not on this ubuntu 22* I am sorry that i am no help.

Comment: These are just the partitions, which I had renamed to D,E,F. Nothing else. I think, I just want these drives to be mounted on startup. How could I do it.

Comment: Use `lsblk` to find the drives and partitions. Usually found at /dev/sdaX than u can Mount them manually with `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/sdaX` u need to `mkdir /mnt/sdaX` beforehand. If that works you can create fstab rules to automount on startup using their UUID and not the /dev/sdaX method. Ubuntu should mount your drives for you if you click on them in you explorer. To let this process.become automatic you have to modify fstab and add the partitions you want. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab